# How to Check Which Version of Team Foundation Server on my Machine (client side)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, version

Sounds like a simple question, but it's giving me a headache. I've tried looking under the Help menu in Visual Studio, in "About Visual Studio", but this only tells me that I have Team Explorer for Visual Studio installed on my machine, not the version I have installed.

I need to know the version. I've looked under program files but did not find anything to indicate the version.

I am currently running Visual Studio 2012, updated to the most latest release. Please note I need to know the version of TFS on my local machine, not on the server. Just simply what version of TFS is installed on my laptop??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS isn't installed client-side.  On the client you use Team Explorer, which is part of Visual Studio.  So the only version on the client-side that is important is the Visual Studio version which you get from Help->About.